# How could xpath extract these contents?

Tags: html, xpath

There have a pice of HTML code like this.
How could I get the title content?

```
<a class="question_link" href="/n/1639322" target="_blank">
<div class="question_text_icons">
<span></span>
</div>
"
This is the page title, which I want to get.
"
</a>
```

my xpath is

```
//a[@class="question_link"]/text()
```

but the output was

```
"\n"
"\nThis is the page title, which I want to get.\n"
```

I only want to "This is the page title, which I want to get.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to locate the inner div and get the following text sibling:

```
//a[@class="question_link"]/div[@class="question_text_icons"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Or, get the `last` text node:

```
//a[@class="question_link"]/text()[last()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option is, by using `normalize-space()` in predicate to filter out empty text nodes :

```
//a[@class="question_link"]/text()[normalize-space()]
```